# EJB Lookup works, but method call don't

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jboss, ejb, lookup

I have an instance of a JBoss EAP 6.1 where i deployed 2 EJB applications.
The server starts without errors!

Now I have created a javaSE application to call these EJBs.

And here is the problem...

If I make lookup of EJB from `applicationA/EJBBean!br.com.sample.EJBRemote` it works fine, and I can call any method form it.

But, I make lookup of EJB from `applicationB/EJBBean!br.com.sample.EJBRemote` it works fine to. But, when I call a method, the javaSE application stops. I got no errors, no outputs.
I put a breakpoint on first line of the method implementation and i saw that is not executed.

My lookup code is following:

```
public static <T> T getEJB(final String moduleName, final String beanName, final Class<T> viewClass) throws NamingException {
    final String lookupName = aplicationName + "/" + beanName + "!" + viewClass.getName();
    return (T) ic.lookup(lookupName);
}
```

I call this from a main method:

```
 final MyRemote beanA = EJBUtils.getEJB("appA", "MyBean", MyRemote.class);
 final MyRemote beanB = EJBUtils.getEJB("appB", "MyBean", MyRemote.class);
```

Both of them works well

But when I do:

```
beanA.methodA(); // This works and prints "methodA" onto console.
beanB.methodA(); // This doesn't work. And dont print any thing onto console.
System.out.println("...") // This line doesn't execute
```

Comment: Hi. I checked your case and both methods are invoking just fine on my machine. Can you post the code of the client along with the InitialContext parameters you are using? Do you package appA as appA.jar and appB as appB.jar (both ejb jars)?

Answer (score 0):

you're trying to lookup the same bean from two different deployments.  i've never seen this really.  you should have BeanA in BeanARemote, BeanA jar, etc.  BeanB as BeanBRemote, BeanB jar, etc.  i imagine if you wrap the whole thing in a catch block you'll see the exceptino that is getting thrown when you call a method on BeanB.  the lookup doesn't always throw exception until you try to use it.

Answer (score -1):

Looks like memory issue. Go to JVM installed folder and look for heap dump. You will definitely get some clues.

Comment: That clarifies the problem is only in applicationB and not related to ApplicationA. Few guesses: 1) Check your JVM arguments 2) the main class mentioned for applicationB should be available in Jar 3)Clean and redeploy everything

Comment: Yeap. But what am I missing? I moved the classes from applicationB  to applicationA and it works. What I need to do for applicationB works? Some idea?

Comment: The strange thing is that I can lookup for EJB. And there is no errors output!